# Problems moving Wordpress from local server to live site

Tags: wordpress, ftp, filezilla

I'm making my first steps learning to code and working with Wordpress. I've been watching some tutorials and then I decided to make my own theme on localhost so like this I could continue learning from the practice.

After some months of learning I finally made a wordpress theme. And now I want to launch it in a live site to show it to the world!

I have been reading a lot of posts and tutorials explaining the apparently easy but hard method of move a Wordpress site from local to live.

I tryied it but I can't see my site online. That's why I would like to tell you how I did it, maybe I'm omitting an step or there is something that I'm doing wrong?

1) I already have a site online. So my idea is to keep my actual site but make a subfolder inside with my wordpress. So like this I have two sites in the same domain: www.myactualsite.com/newwordpress

2) I open my Filezilla, I went to my actual site directory and I created a new directory inside where I pasted all the content of my wordpress directory from the local host.

3) I exported the database from the local host site and with the help of my text editor I replaced all the local host url's for my new live site url's.

4) I created a new database in my live site, and I imported all the content of the database I created in local host.

5) In Filezilla, I updated the wp-config file of my wordpress and I wrote the name of the new database I just created, the password of that database, and my user name for that database.

Then I went to my new site address, but I can't see anything, it didn't even show an error. Just a white screen.

Do you have some suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easier method is,

- Install new copy of WordPress on that path.
- Export your current WordPress, by tools `>` export
- Go to new WordPress, click on import `>` WordPress `>` Upload the file.

that's it.